# Does Geoserver support SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, geoserver

I have a geometry layer stored in SQL Server 2016. I've downloaded Geoserver's plug-in from the [web site](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-install).

Geoserver Documentation clearly states that Geoserver doesn't support SQL Server on default. I've followed the instructions and I was able to see Microsoft SQL Server as a data source.

When I try to connect to my SQL Server the interface is just different from documentation. It doesn't even ask any user credentials and the name of the data source is also different from documentation. 
[image]

**The interface;**

[image]

My question is Geoserver doesn't really support SQL Server 2016 or am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks 
H.

Answer (score 0):

A JNDI connection should already be configured with the connection parameters in the web servlet container (tomcat, jetty, etc). Therefore geoserver doesn't need to ask again. Maybe what you need is the JDBC connection next to it in the list.

I'm not sure if anyone has tested it with sqlserver 2016 but feel free to update the documentation if you find it does (or if it didn't work too).